# GPUImage framework

Tags: objective-c, xcode, image, render

I'm attempting to run/test the GPUImage framework to see if it fits my requirements. But, I am unable to launch anything within the frameworks examples. I get the same error for each example > Unknown Type Name CVOpenGLESTextureCacheRef and Various other errors like Implicit declaration of function CVOpenGLESTextureCacheCreate

And so on.

There are about 9 errors total. If anyone knows why this would be happening please let me know. Thank you very much in advance.

UPDATE:
As it turns out, Brad pointed out that I may need to update my XCode from 4.2 to 4.3 to make this framework compile. I not only needed to upgrade the XCode but also needed to update my OS to the latest Lion version to get XCode 4.3 to install. This corrected my issue. I can now run the examples and test this framework. Thanks again Brad for this great addition!